# Library postinstall script fails on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to create a x-platform Node.js library. Everything works fine on *nix, but the postinstall script fails on Windows -

the postinstall script is invoked via package.json as usual:

```
"scripts":{
  "postinstall":"./assets/postinstall.sh"
}
```

and the script itself doesn't really do much anyway, it's just like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;

if [ "$skip_postinstall" == "yes" ]; then
    echo "skipping postinstall routine.";
    exit 0;
fi

export FORCE_COLOR=1;
export skip_postinstall="yes";
```

but I get this error:

> $ npm i
>
> > npm-link-up@0.1.320 postinstall C:\Users\denman\codes\ores\npm-link-up
> >     ./assets/postinstall.sh
>
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm
>   ERR! npm-link-up@0.1.320 postinstall: `./assets/postinstall.sh` npm
>   ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the npm-link-up@0.1.320
>   postinstall script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
>   There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Have you tried defining the path in your `postinstall` script as `assets/postinstall.sh`, i.e. omitting the `./` part from the beginning?

Comment: @RobC I think if you omit the `./` it won't work on *nix, but let me try it

Comment: I think it's probably the case where the script is being piped through a shell other than bash. I believe the NPM scripts are basically just executed like `echo script | bash`, but on windows it might be different by default, even if you run the npm install command from a bash shell on windows?

Comment: Hello there @AlexanderMills. found any solution? I hate windows =) software companies should ban windows for God´s sake